# Managed package cannot see a class from another managed package

Tags: managed-package, reflection

We have a following setup:

- a managed package **pkg_a** which provides a global virtual class **Cls_A** to be extended
- a managed package **pkg_b** which contains a global class **Cls_B** that **extends pkg_a.Cls_A**
- a static method in pkg_a's class which tries to retrieve a Type given its full name:

  ```
  public static Type findType(String fullName) {
      if (String.isBlank(fullName)) {
          return null;
      }

      Type foundType = Type.forName(fullName);
      if (foundType == null) {
          // now try to find it locally without package prefix
          foundType = Type.forName('', fullName);

          // try with package prefix
          if (foundType == null && fullName.contains('.')) {
              List<String> splitStr = fullName.split('\\.', 2);

              String namespace = splitStr[0];
              String className = splitStr[1];

              foundType = Type.forName(namespace, className);
          }
      }
      return foundType;
  }
  ```

When this method is called within pkg_a context:

```
    Type t = MyClass.findType('pkg_b.Cls_B');
```

it returns null for some reason. Does anyone know what are the possible reasons for this? Why wouldn't one managed package see a global class from another managed package, especially if this other class is extending package's own class?

What was checked so far:

- pkg_b.Cls_B is set to depend on the latest version of pkg_a
- Cls_B methods are public
- user running the pkg_a process which calls the findType() method has a System Adminstrator profile with access to all classes and packages, so it's unlikely that it's a permissions problem
- the most puzzling bit: this behaviour was noticed on an Enterprise edition org; on dev orgs everything works correctly

Comment: What happens if you try to call it explicitly without type.forName() ? Are you able to instantiate the class ?

Comment: I've tried to instantiate it directly from Dev console, worked without a problem.

Comment: You may have to add the namespace in the type.forname instead of using '' since the class from one package is in a different namespace that the local one the dev console uses

Comment: or maybe call it like that since it is a string: Type t = MyClass.findType('pkg_b__Cls_B');

Comment: @Eric - Do you mean something like Type.forName('pkg_b', 'pkg_b.Cls_B')? If you check the findType() method, it already accounts for the namespace within the class name string passed to it.

Comment: @ItaiShmida - Namespaced classes in Apex are referenced with dot notation, double-underscore is usually reserved for SObjects. It's strange because the class in question can be referenced and found by using dot-notation in the passed string without problems on dev orgs with both packages installed.

Comment: Still I think it is worth a check

Comment: @IvanVrtarić type.forname('pkg_b','cls_b') would be how it would be used. I have seen this work when putting the ns in the class name string does not. Put it in as a debug and a test to see if it works. Worth a shot since what you are doing is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, other colleagues have run into the same issue, and found the underlying reason.

After pkg_a was installed, each package that was installed after it added a version dependency to pkg_a's classes, e.g. after pkg_b v1.23 was installed, pkg_a's classes had pkg_b v1.23 dependency added to them. After the packages were updated, however, all classes in pkg_a that weren't modified/updated didn't have their dependencies updated either. So, after pkg_b was updated to v1.25, unmodified classes from pkg_a still had a dependency on pkg_b v1.23. Cls_B was introduced in v1.25, so an unmodified class from pkg_a couldn't see it since it still had a dependency on v1.23. Changing the dependency version manually while logged on as a Subscriber didn't work, SFDC returned an error "Only code in local namespace can be changed" (or a similar message in the same vein).

The problem was solved by modifying the class in pkg_a that tries to reference classes from other packages - an empty line or two were added - and creating a patch release which was installed on the target org. This caused SFDC to see the affected class as modified, recompiling it and updating the package dependencies on it.