# Managed package not able to dynamically instantiate orgs default namespace class

Tags: apex

I would have thought, given the other questions on the same subject that I would be able to solve this fairly easily, but it does not seem to be the case. I have tried solutions from both the following questions without success -

[Managed package cannot see a class from another managed package](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146768/managed-package-cannot-see-a-class-from-another-managed-package)

[A class in one namespace dynamically instantiating an object outside its namespace](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160614/a-class-in-one-namespace-dynamically-instantiating-an-object-outside-its-namespa)

I have a managed package which has a helper class called ObjectHelper which is able to instantiate classes given their string name. This package has been installed in another Dev Org. I am trying to call ObjectHelper to instantiate a class created in the Dev Org. Here is the code which tries to instantiate the class (based on one of the answers in the above questions) -

```
String className = config.Class_Name__c;

Integer index = className.indexOf('.');
if (index != -1) {
    t = Type.forName(className.substring(index), className.substring(index + 1, className.length()));
} else {
    t = Type.forName(null, className);
}
```

I have also tried the following -

```
String className = config.Class_Name__c;

t = Type.forName(className);

if (t == null)
    t = Type.forName('', className);
```

Nothing is working. I have tried to instantiate the class in anonymous code on the Dev Org using the following and it works fine -

```
String className = config.Class_Name__c
System.debug('TYPE - ' + Type.forName(null, className));
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. The class being instantiated needed to have itself and its constructors be `global`. They were originally set to `public`. Once the scope was changed the installed package found the type and was able to construct it as necessary using the following code as mentioned above -

```
String className = config.Class_Name__c;

Integer index = className.indexOf('.');
if (index != -1) {
    t = Type.forName(className.substring(index), className.substring(index + 1, className.length()));
} else {
    t = Type.forName(null, className);
}
```